# Кеширование cURL

Tags: curl

Есть скрипт, который с помощью cUrl запрашивает данные с сайта. Например:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://site.ru/get_orders.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$pg = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Проблема: результат исполнения всегда один и тот же, т.е. в переменной `$pg` один и тот же контент.

При этом если открывать через браузер ссылку http://site.ru/get_orders.php то отображается нормально.

Пробовал менять `CURLOPT_URL` на сам сайт. Выкачивает, отображает html. Снова возвращаю на get_orders.php - показывает то же самое. Пробовал вообще вырубать сайт-источник - и все-равно CURL вернул то же значение.
Ощущение, что где-то кешируется результат. А где - непонятно.

Есть идеи?

Результат curl_getinfo:

```
* About to connect() to .....ru port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ... ... * connected
> GET /get_orders.php HTTP/1.1
Host: ....ru
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.6.3
< Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 14:51:09 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 10
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
<
* Connection #0 to host .....ru left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Пробовал запускать curl через ssh:

```
curl site:ru/get_orders.php
```

и он возвратил то же самое значение.

```
file_get_contents()
```

тоже.

Точно какое-то кэширование...
Есть идеи?

Comment: Пробовал запускать curl через ssh:
    curl site:ru/get_orders.php
и он возвратил то же самое значение. Значит точно какое-то кэширование...

Comment: Вместо комментария лучше добавлять важную информацию прямо в вопрос, используя кнопку [edit].

Answer (score 5):

Нашел причину. Дело было не в кэшировании :)

Проблема была в том, что работая через SSH он стучался по IPv6 на другой сервер.
Т.е. при открытии через браузер я попадал на локальный сервак (т.к. прописан только ip), а через SSH запрос уходил к другому серваку.